# Maven Build failure. Updating maven (without fixing) it builds, why?

Tags: java, maven

my system config is

> Apache Maven 3.0.5
>   Maven home: D:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\java\maven
>   Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: D:\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
>   Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: Cp1252
>   OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

when i build my maven project it returns this error:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 8.678s
Finished at: Fri Jun 17 20:27:43 CEST 2016
Final Memory: 31M/312M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on project eWheel: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: For artifact {org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on project eWheel: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: For artifact {org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: For artifact {org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRTException: For artifact {org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty.
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.validateIdentity(DefaultArtifact.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init>(DefaultArtifact.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createDependencyArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:57)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.LegacyRepositorySystem.createDependencyArtifact(LegacyRepositorySystem.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.getManagedVersionMap(MavenProject.java:1624)
    at org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.deepCopy(MavenProject.java:1992)
    at org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.<init>(MavenProject.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.createArchive(MavenArchiver.java:501)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.performPackaging(WarMojo.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute(WarMojo.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 20 more


For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

i don't understand why...

this is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!-- clip -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>  
               <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>  
               <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>  
               <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <!-- clip -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
            <version>6.0</version>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- clip -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- clip -->
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <!-- Weld EE embedded profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.4</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <!-- Weld EE embedded profile -->
        <!-- Glassfish embedded profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-glassfish-embedded</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-payara-embedded</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
                    <artifactId>payara-embedded-all</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.1.161</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <!-- Glassfish embedded profile -->
        <!-- JBoss AS profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-jbossas-managed</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <!-- JBoss AS profile -->
        <!-- remote container Boss AS 7.1 -->
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-jbossas-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <!-- remote container Boss AS 7.1 -->
        <!-- remote container Glassfish 3.1.2 -->
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-glassfish-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <!-- remote container Glassfish 3.1.2 -->
        <!-- remote container Payara -->
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-payara-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <!-- remote container payara-->
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the problem is a missing version in dependency but...
if i use maven 3.3.9 without fixing it builds ...

can someone help me to understand the reason?

Comment: Can you post your POM?

Comment: sorry, i forgotten

Comment: Well the error is clear cut: the dependency `shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven` does not have a  `<version>` (it is inside your `<dependencyManagement>` section). You must specify a version. [Maybe 2.2.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven/2.2.2)?

Comment: this is the problem, but why it work with maven 3.3.9?

Comment: @Marco The answers here are not really correct, you have put the dependency into the wrong section. It should be under dependencies, not under dependencyManagement. After doing this, you can remove the version again, since the version comes from arquillian-bom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget the version on one of your dependencies?

> For artifact
>   {org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:null:jar}:
>   The version cannot be empty.

I commented in the wrong post, sorry armadinho.

This might be it
- Disallow the programmatic injection of project dependencies MNG-5818.

- https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.9/release-notes.html

Answer (score 1):

Try adding version number in under dependency management.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>  
           <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>  
           <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>

           <!-- Try adding version here -->
           <version>...</version>

           <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: this is the problem, but why it work with maven 3.3.9?

Comment: this fix the problem but doesn't tell me why it builds updating maven